# cURL Bash does not login

Tags: bash, curl, authentication

I try to login to a website with cURL.
This is my code... but i everytime got back to login page =/

```
USER="Dantes9999"
PASS="******"
TEST=$(curl -s --cookie-jar cookie --dump-header header_cookie  https://de.metin2.gameforge.com | grep -o '<form action=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"] method' | sed -e 's/^\s*<form action=["'"'"']//' -e 's/["'"'"'] method$//')
LOGINDATA="'username=$USER&password=$PASS'"
LOGINRESPONSE=$(curl -s -L -b header_cookie -d $LOGINDATA $TEST)
LOGINRESPONSE1=$(curl -s -L -b cookie -d $LOGINDATA $TEST)
echo "" > header_cookie
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"Sicherheitswort"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Sicherheit"
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"Drachenm"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Drachenm"    
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"login"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = negative Login BtN"    
fi
echo "" > cookie
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"Sicherheitswort"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Sicherheit"
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"Drachenm"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Drachenm"    
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"login"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = negative Login BtN"    
fi
```

so hopefully somebody know, how to get this.
With every request i get a new token and the matching cookies for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't grep this site but rather send form data with post.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="Dantes9999"
PASS="******"
LOGINRESPONSE=$(curl -X POST -F 'username=$USER' -F 'password=$PASS' -c yourcookie https://de.metin2.gameforge.com/user/login)
LOGINRESPONSE1=$(curl -X GET -b yourcookie https://de.metin2.gameforge.com/main/index)
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"account"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Sicherheit"
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"Drachenm"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Drachenm"    
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE1 == *"login"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = negative Login BtN"    
fi
echo "" > cookie
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"Sicherheitswort"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Sicherheit"
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"Drachenm"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = positive Drachenm"    
fi
if [[ $LOGINRESPONSE == *"login"* ]]; then
      echo "$USER + $PASS = negative Login BtN"    
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work..this account exist and the code say, that it does not exist...

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work..this account exist and the code say, that it does not exist...
On every site is written "account" somewere... so this is not a valid test, if the login is done

So there is the "-L" missing.. 
The idea is good, but not working